# Unable to install kafka in my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, laravel-10

I am implementing a web tracker activity using Apache Kafka with a Laravel application using the “php-rdkafka” library .
The first step was to install dependencies with the following commands :

`composer require edenhill/librdkafka`
 `composer require phprdkafka/php-rdkafka`

But when i run these commands , i got this error :

> Could not find a matching version of package edenhil
> l/librdkafka. Check the package spelling, your versi
> on constraint and that the package is available in a
> stability which matches your minimum-stability (sta
> ble).

How could i solve it ?

I am a newbie in Laravel and i am using 10.30.1 version

Thanks !!!

Comment: I don't see the package for `edenhill/librdkafka`. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: `phprdkafka/php-rdkafka` doesn't seem to exist, either. The only reference I see to it is a medium.com article

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP extension, not a composer package. Normally you'd install it with PEAR/PECL.

You can find the installation guides [here](https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.html):

> Linux, Unix, and OS X users may run the following command to install the extension:
> `$ sudo pecl install rdkafka`
>
> Add the following line to your php.ini file:
> `extension=rdkafka.so`

Comment: i've tried to run the command but i got this : No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/rdkafka"
install failed

Comment: Sorry it's was a problem of network

Comment: Now , i got this :configure: error: Please reinstall the rdkafka distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/rdkafka/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-rdkafka' failed